# Отключить LOGON триггер

Tags: sql, sql-server, триггер

Создал в учебных целях триггер входа в систему. Хотел сделать, чтобы определённого пользователя SQL Server не пускал. В итоге сам зайти не могу :( Естественно, всегда заходил под виндовой аутентификацией, только после написания триггера поставил смешанную. Пароль sa не задавал и не знаю, поэтому никак сейчас не могу подключиться даже в режиме минимальной конфигурации и убить этот триггер. Помогите.

```
CREATE TABLE Examples.LoginLog
(
    LoginLogId int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT PKLoginLog PRIMARY KEY,
    LoginName sysname NOT NULL,
    LoginTime datetime2(0) NOT NULL ,
    ApplicationName sysname NOT NULL
);

CREATE LOGIN LogonTriggerLogging WITH PASSWORD= 'PASSWORD$1';
CREATE USER LogonTriggerLogging FOR LOGIN LogonTriggerLogging;
GRANT INSERT ON Examples.LoginLog TO LogonTriggerLogging;

CREATE TRIGGER LogonTrigger
ON ALL SERVER
WITH EXECUTE AS 'LogonTriggerLogging'
FOR LOGON
AS
IF ORIGINAL_LOGIN() = 'Login_NotAllowed'
    THROW 50000,'Unauthorized Access',1;
ELSE
    INSERT INTO MyDB.Examples.LoginLog(LoginName,LoginTime,ApplicationName)
    VALUES (ORIGINAL_LOGIN(),SYSDATETIME(),APP_NAME());

CREATE LOGIN Login_NotAllowed WITH PASSWORD = 'PASSWORD$1'
```

Дальше ни под кем не могу зайти. Ни под LogonTriggerLogging, ни под Login_NotAllowed(оно и понятно), ни под sa, ни под виндовой аутентификацией. Sql Server ругается и говорит, что срабатывает триггер, и что он меня не пустит. Номер ошибки 17892

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @Yaant, получилось зайти в однопользовательском режиме, создать юзера с правами sysadmin, но когда потом захожу под этим юзером в многопользовательском режиме, опять триггер не пускает.

Comment: Так в однопользовательском режиме триггер отключите, и всё. Или вопрос в том, почему триггер не работает как надо? Насколько помню любая ошибка в logon-триггере (даже не преднамеренная) вызывает невозможность логина. Например, могли `CREATE USER` и `GRANT` сделать не в той базе, в которой нужно (в _master_, вместо MyDB), тогда триггер не отработает правильно.

Comment: @i-one, вот дела. Когда я пытаюсь задизаблить триггер, SQL сервер пишет, типа БД подключена в однопользовательском режиме и поэтому запрос не отработает

Comment: Я всё аккуратно проделал согласно коду в вопросе, и у меня оно сработало. Если что-то не так (нет таблицы, или не хватает прав), тогда да - ошибка и никто не заходит. Но `DISABLE TRIGGER LogonTrigger ON ALL SERVER` сработало (если зайти через [DAC](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/diagnostic-connection-for-database-administrators)).

Comment: @i-one, спасибо, позже попробую. Вероятно, я делаю `INSERT INTO` не в ту таблицу. А Вы пробовали зайти под  `Login_NotAllowed`? Пишется ли чего в таблицу `Examples.LoginLog` ?

Comment: Да, в таблицу данные пишутся, но я не обратил внимания, пишется ли что-то для *Login_NotAllowed*. Скорее всего не писалось. Этим логином, как и следовало ожидать, зайти не получилось. Однако ошибка при этом всё равно 17892, а не 50000. По-видимому инфраструктура генерирует конкретную ошибку и не пробрасывает исключение из триггера.

Comment: @i-one, для _Login_NotAllowed_ пишутся следующие данные в таблицу  `Examples.LoginLog`: _LoginName:_ `NT Service\SQL TELEMETRY`, _ApplicationName:_ `SQLServerCEIP`. А ошибка у меня в триггере была такая: я писал лог в несущетсвующую базу данных. То есть я создал таблицу, но когда начал объяснять триггеру, куда писать данные - неправильно обратился к созданной таблице. Спасибо, что помогли разобраться)