# Как запретить подключение определенного приложения к ms sql server?

Tags: sql-server

Монитор активности в management studio определяет имя приложения, через которое запущен тот или иной процесс. Можно ли запретить подключения от определённого приложения? [image: Монитор активности]

Comment: По идее logon trigger должен помочь. В нём проверить название приложения и выбросить исключение. Вот [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1075504/193999), который нетрудно адаптировать.